# How could I handle timeout request in koa?

Tags: node.js, koa

For example:

```
var app = require('koa')();
app.use(function *(next) {
    var start = new Date();
    yield next;
});
app.use(function *(next) {
    var result = yield loadData();
    this.body = result;
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Let's assume that if `loadData` returns data more than 1 second, then I want `this.body = 'there is a timeout'`. How could I achieve this? I don't think `setTimeout` is able to deal with this. And I tried `this.response.setTimeout` function, but it said that `setTimeout` is undefined. Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Just looked-up `npm` registry and found this package: [koa-timeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-timeout). Looks like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think this may solve my issue. Maybe I didn't describe my problem in detail. Is there anyway to convert `loadData` into an async function? I want to give the result to `this.body` when an async function returns the result. Seems no way... Is there any suggestion? Do I have to write c++ code for the `loadData` function?

Answer (score 0):

you can always convert it to a promise instead. like

```
`loadData().then((onCompletion) => {
//take the time here
timeOut = timeEnd - timeStart;
timeOut >= 1sec ? this.body = 'there is a timeout' : this.body = onCompletion 
}).((onFailure) => {
//do something if it fails
});`
```

of course this will not work unless your loadData returns a promise

Comment: Yes, I don't think I could achieve my goal without modifying the code in the  bottom layer of the `loadData` or the `koa`. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.  You yield the assert timeout with your loadData() and pass second parameter as int in ms, in your case `1000`.

https://github.com/cojs/assert-timeout

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
var app = require('koa')();
app.use(function *(next) {
    this.req.connection.setTimeout(0);
    var start = new Date();
    yield next;
});
app.use(function *(next) {
    var result = yield loadData();
    this.body = result;
});
app.listen(8080);
```